# How do I insert data into my database using Entity Framework .NET Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I was using the .NET framework version of EF, I'd simply do `using(var db = new dbContext())` and I'd be able to instantiate a new context and insert data using `db.<tableName>.add()`

However, this doesn't work for .NET core. When I attempt to instantiate a new context, I get an error message requiring that a

> DbContextOptions object is passed through to the context object to instantiate it.

This is `DbContext class`:

```
public SolicitorContext(DbContextOptions<SolicitorContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

Obviously the options object needs to be passed through here to init the object.

Comment: What's your question? Yes you need to supply options to the constructor.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Full/Core frameworks. EF Core also supports parameterless constructor, just add it to your db context class, e.g. `public SolicitorContext() { }`

Answer (score 2):

```
var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YOURCONTEXT>()
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YOURCONNSTRING"))
            .Options;

using (var yourDB = new YOURCONTEXT(dbOptions))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DbContextOptionsBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder):

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContext> dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<dbContext>();
dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
```

And pass the `dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options` as the parameter `options` when initializing your context:

```
using (var db = new dbContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options))
```